# Is storing numpy array as value in a cell of pandas dataframe a good practice?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

So if we create a dataframe with numpy arrays as values to col2 like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [11, 12], 'col2': [np.array([1.2,2.3,3.4]),np.array([4,5,6])]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

output :

```
   col1             col2
0    11  [1.2, 2.3, 3.4]
1    12        [4, 5, 6]
```

Question -
Should we save numpy arrays to dataframe like this, at all ? and if yes then what could be some problems that someone might face if he/she uses this design

Comment: Your questions seems a bit generic. Could you please explain your use case?

Comment: In general it's preferred to either split the arrays into separate columns or explode them into separate rows, depending on what the data represent.

Comment: Using a dictionary is more efficient if you have only two columns. If you intend to use a dataframe temporary store data tthen his approach is fine.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.